# What is swiftly on mac? It is driving me crazy

Tags: macos

I upgraded to Mavericks a few days ago and since then I keep getting a pop up floating search box randomly. I do not know what triggered it and I do not know where it is from. It is driving me crazy. Can anyone tell me?

I have alfred and shiftit installed.

[image]

Comment: I'd argue that this is offtopic for stack overflow. It's likely on topic at: http://apple.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Not a question for [so]. Try asking on [su]

Answer (score 12):

It is from QQ.

I'm fairly sure it was introduced with 3.0 on the mac side, though I tend to skip versions so I'm not sure.  Since it is part of QQ, closing the app will also stop swiftly from stealing cmd+cmd.

- Open QQ
- Go to QQ => Preferences in the menu bar (or cmd + ,)
- Swiftly will be the tab on the far right
- Set the "Launch Swiftly" trigger to empty

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I believe it's from QQ. QQ has this new feature where you doube tap the command key to call out a Swiftly search box that functions similarly to Spotlight Search.